# capture error and pipe into awk

Tags: awk, pdftotext

I want to capture error message and send to awk (for example, pdftotext gives "Incorrect password" message when pdf file is encrypted) so that awk can print it.

As it is the command below counts the words in the pdf file. However for files with passwords, the command return 0 count, which clashes with pdf images without passwords (returning 0 count also).

```
pdftotext -q file.pdf - | awk 'BEGIN {w=w+NF; if(w>=30) {print (w-1); exit}} END {print w-1}'
```

I am stuck at

```
pdftotext 2>&1 file.pdf - | awk 'BEGIN {w=w+NF; if(w>=30) {print (w-1); exit}} END {print w-1}'
```

Should the pdf file is password protected, then "Command Line Error: Incorrect password" gets piped into awk. How do I print that phrase? (There would be no word count in this case.)

A. Das

Comment: Can you show the output of `pdftotext`

Comment: @hek2mgl file.pdf   Command Line Error: Incorrect password

Comment: Does the answer solves your problem?

Comment: @hek2mgl I can't see how it would

Comment: @ALvinDas I can see how it would. Did you try it?

Comment: @ED Morton Ok Ed I did. I cannot make it work for me

Comment: @ED Morton pdftotext 2>&1 fr.na.pdf | awk "{print}" passes the error to awk, but with my word awk count above, I have to test for the error in awk and print it, if the pdf file is pw protected. Maybe you can help.

Comment: Currently, I can do either the word count as posted above, OR grabbing the error from pdftotext: pdftotext 2>&1 file.pdf | awk '/Error/ {print $1}', but I can't do both. Some pointers will do.

Comment: @ALvinDas - update your question with some sample input and expected output along with what you've tried so far and in what way that doesn't work for you. I have no idea now what it is you're trying to do as the posted answer would do what I thought you wanted and your comments don't make it any clearer how it's failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what you're asking for:

```
pdftotext file.pdf - 2>&1 | awk '
    /Command Line Error:/ { print; exit}
    { w += NF }
    END { print w+0 }
'
```

Your main problem seems to be that you had your whole script inside the BEGIN section and that's executed before any input is processed.

Answer (score 1):

To reroute errors you want to redirect stderr to stdout.

Use

```
pdftotext -q file.pdf 2>&1 | awk '...' #Whatever post processing you do
```